# Why use mongoose schema in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I was learning Node.js and Mongoose. Then, I cam across the term schema which is defined as the description of the structure of the data, default values and validation. So, as we know schema looks basically like this:

```
var TaskSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    priority: Number
});
```

The question I would like to ask is Why should we care about the description of structure of data that the schema allows to achieve, I mean, what is the main point in the use of schemas in mongoose? if you say, validation, then can't we achieve that with express-validator package? or...

Comment: What if you don't build a web server so you don't use `express-validator`

Comment: @MickaelB., hey)), sorry I just wanted to understand the main use of schemas in mongoose, pls can you very briefly explain. It is very important for me

Comment: This question could be generalized out to the use of schemas in all of Javascript.  Not only DB's but JSON, forms, validation, etc...

Answer (score 0):

> Everything in Mongoose starts with a Schema. Each schema maps to a MongoDB collection and defines the shape of the documents within that collection.

See the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition) for more information.

> Schemas not only define the structure of your document and casting of properties, they also define document instance methods, static Model methods, compound indexes, and document lifecycle hooks called middleware.

---

This is what allows you to communicate with the database easily using mongoose. It's not just for validation.

Comment: all right I think the main point I cannot get is "maps to a MongoDB collection and defines the shape of the documents within that collection", that is, why need to define the shape of the documents. In what situation the definition can be helpful?

Comment: It's so the documents have the same structure (even of MongoDB allows documents in a collection to have different structure) then you can use the model to easily insert a read documents from the database and convert them easily.

Comment: So, you mean schemas help to acheve CONSISTENCY of data so that data in document has identical structure?

Comment: yes that's one reason why you want to use mongoose or another ORM. Check this [article](https://www.stackchief.com/blog/Top%204%20Reasons%20to%20Use%20Mongoose%20with%20MongoDB)